# How easy is it to find a job in Poland for an IT professional on temporary residence permit?

Tags: poland

Say, I'm an IT professional with 10+ years experience. How easy or difficult would be for me to find a job in Poland (given I'm currently living in Wroclaw on TRP)? How long should I reasonably expect the job search to take?

- I do not have any Polish language (or any other EU language) skills whatsoever.
- English is my second language but am reasonably fluent.
- I don't mind working at lower level jobs than my current (as long as it's IT). For example, I don't mind work as a team member even if currently I'm in lead roles.
- My IT skills are good enough but there's nothing that'd stand out in a huge way.
- I don't have any professional/social network in Poland.
- I'm willing to move to any city.
- I have about a month to find a new job.

Comment: English is an EU language and will remain so even after Brexit ;)

Comment: Great! So, not being able to speak polish is not a problem in Poland as long as one is fluent in English?

Comment: I didn't write that and I don't know, I am just making a small – and admittedly not very helpful – comment on your second bullet point. You do speak an EU language, namely English. I can add that *legally*, there is at least one type of work permit that does not require Polish language skills and could therefore be open to you (the EU Blue Card). Whether many Polish businesses would hire you, I have no idea.

Comment: Polish is required in most companies at the conversational level. Many companies have no idea how to hire non-EU people according to local rules and they are afraid of possible paperwork. If you already have kartu czasowego pobytu you probaly know one may need two to five months to receive a new one (unless you can use the old TRP)  so all this time you cannot work with the new company, and your future boss should be agree to wait for you all this time.

Comment: Thank you. Good point about the 2-5 months wait, guess the laws ensure that they really need the new employee enough to wait for months.